# change background of text field in searchview of android sdk

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, searchview

I am making an app and I have an activity with a searchview. My point is that I want to change the background color of the text field (the black rectangle in screnn shot).

My drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="rectangle"
         android:padding="10dp">

 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".SearchActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="160sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/search_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60sp"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
        android:focusable="false" >

    </SearchView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot: http://imageshack.com/a/img829/3203/pd85.png

Can anybody help me with that?
thanks

Comment: Paste the drawables (or link to them if they're not XML)

Comment: you have the drawable in the pastebin link.... in the bottom, after the activity xml

Comment: The one in the XML may be the one used for the background but certainly not @drawable/searchview

Comment: Juan, the second in pastebin is the searchview.xml in the drawable folder. Why do you think not?

Comment: i'm added the code to here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little detective work you'll see that if you look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#SearchView.0mQueryTextView) for the `SearchView` widget, you will see it extends `LinearLayout` with some added functionality. Looking at the line `#242` it contains a widget (specifically a `SearchAutoComplete` which extends the `AutoCompleteTextView` which in the end extends `EditText`.

With that said, you'll need to modify the background attribute of that child element, with something on the lines of this:

```
SearchView c = findViewById(R.id.searchView); 
EditText e = (EditText)c.findViewById(c.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
         e.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //←If you just want a color
         e.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE));
         //↑ If you want a drawable ↑
```

#### Useful links:

- [Source for SearchView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#SearchView.0mQueryTextView)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still  trying. i got 'EditText cannot be resolved to a type'. I have to extend the class? This have to be done with java?

Comment: i got 'c cannot be resolved to a type'. I have to import something right?do you know what is?

Comment: Sorry for that, I renamed the variables to c and e for shorted code, please try now

Comment: Create a drawable that has the desired border (be it XML or 9patch drawable) and call setBackground as in the ↑ code

Comment: thanks. i got it. but i still have a line arround edittext of searchview and is not the border. I don't know whats this..do you know?

Comment: if you want continue this discussion see my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800802/mysterious-line-arround-edittext-from-searchview

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate).setBackground...
```

Also for voice button:

```
mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn).setBackground...
```