# mysterious line arround editText from searchview

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, searchview

I have a searchview and i changed the edittext box of them with a drawable (with java code). However I have a mysterious border that i can't remove. If you see the screenshot you will see the red line that is a border defined in drawable 'editext.xml' My problem is I doesn't know what is the black line arround the edittext. Anybody know what is and how i remove it?

drawable (edittext):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c66262" />          
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />   
</shape>
```

drawable (searchview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="rectangle"
         android:padding="10dp">

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" /> 
<corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

acitivty xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".SearchActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="160sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/search_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60sp"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" >

    </SearchView>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ScreenShot: http://imageshack.com/a/img842/6100/ebsb.jpg

thanks in advance

Comment: This is mysterious indeed. I would now try to figure out if the border belongs to the edittext or the searchview, by removing the stroke of the searchview, and removing the whole edittext, and see if the border disappears. Additionally, I would investigate if there are some default borders applied somewhere. Keep us updated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your red color is set in this line in your edittext shape:

```
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c66262" />
```

maybe set here:

```
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
```

for a black stroke

**Edit:** this is for making red line black. I misunderstood question a bit. Anyhow I think would look nicer this way. My few cents ;-)

Anyhow, if you don't want the black line, then just set the black line (#000000) to let's say white:

```
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
```

or simply get rid of it at all, by just deleting this code here, which looks like it is your black stroke:

```
 <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" /> 
 <corners
  android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
  android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

Comment: ah you want it the other way round :-P

Comment: You should read question carefully, black stroke for border around widget.

Comment: Sorry, but after looking at screenshot I somehow thought that this red line must go... looks a bit strange to me, but well I am not the designer here

Comment: just change in your stroke the color code from `#000000` to `#ffffff`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove following line from drawable(searchview):

stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"